# Pandas interpolate between 2 given numbers, given step increase and within groupby

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, pandas-groupby

This is a loaded question as I can find how each of these are done individually, but want to put it all together, particularly applied by groups. The goal is to to use 2 values as a range and interpolate values between them given a set interval. Next I want a column with the running sum (however, I am familiar with that. It's the interpolate functions that I don't understand within a groupby).

As stated, I started with a basic and it works perfectly, ie:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'minute':[1,3,4,5,8],'value':[1,4,7,10,13]})
max_value = df['minute'].max()

df.index = df.minute
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'minute':range(0,max_value), 'Value':0})
df2.index = df2.minute

df2.value = df.value
df2= df2.fillna(0)
```

But now given an additional column, how do I apply this to 'id' `'a'` and `id` `'h'`?

So given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',    '0',    '10'],
                ['a',   '1',    '10'],
                ['h',   '2',    '15'],
                ['a',   '1',    '10'],
                ['h',   '3',    '20'],
                ['h',   '13',   '5']], columns = ['id','minute','value'])
```

I'd like to generate this output, which would be groupby the `id` column, interpolate by the `minute` column where the min is 0, the max is the max value in that column, and input a 0 in the value column.

Example Output:

```
id  minute  value   sum
a   0        10     10
a   1        20     30
a   2         0     30
a   3         0     30
a   4         0     30
a   5         0     30
a   6         0     30
a   7         0     30
a   8         0     30
a   9         0     30
a   10        0     30
a   11        0     30
a   12        0     30
a   13        0     30
h   0         0      0
h   1         0      0
h   2        15     15
h   3        20     35
h   4         0     35
h   5         0     35
h   6         0     35
h   7         0     35
h   8         0     35
h   9         0     35
h   10        0     35
h   11        0     35
h   12        0     35
h   13        5     40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a `MultiIndex` using the [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) method and then reindex with it. Then use `groupby.cumsum` to create your 'sum' column:

```
min_idx = np.arange(df['minute'].max() + 1)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(), min_idx], names=['id', 'minute'])

df_new = df.set_index(['id', 'minute']).reindex(m_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df_new['sum'] = df_new.groupby('id')['value'].cumsum()
df_new
```

[Out]

```
   id  minute  value  sum
0   a       0     10   10
1   a       1     10   20
2   a       2      0   20
3   a       3      0   20
4   a       4      0   20
5   a       5     10   30
6   a       6      0   30
7   a       7      0   30
8   a       8      0   30
9   a       9      0   30
10  a      10      0   30
11  a      11      0   30
12  a      12      0   30
13  a      13      0   30
14  h       0      0    0
15  h       1      0    0
16  h       2     15   15
17  h       3     20   35
18  h       4      0   35
19  h       5      0   35
20  h       6      0   35
21  h       7      0   35
22  h       8      0   35
23  h       9      0   35
24  h      10      0   35
25  h      11      0   35
26  h      12      0   35
27  h      13      5   40
```

Comment: I just noticed an issue with my data. Since that 'minute' column is in minutes, there are some rows that will have the same minute and id, thus creating a non-unique multi-index. I made a quick edit to the dataframe above to show it. but since I didn't have it in the originally,  I am accepting this answer, as that was my fault/miss, and this solution does work within the OP.

Comment: Yeh may just need to dedupe original DataFrame before this transformation. eg. `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'minute'], inplace=True)` ?

Comment: ya, but if I drop duplicates, then it drops the values of the duplicates, I need to combine those so it's one row with the sum of those values. I'm working on doing that now. Was just curious if you knew it off the the top of your head.

Comment: ah I see, in that case maybe `df = df.groupby(['id', 'minute']).sum().reset_index()` first ?

Comment: yup I literally just did that right before reading this. perfect. Thanks for your extra help with that. I know it can be annoying that a poster will pry for more help after the original solution, so much appreciate the extended help